# Python, Concise code on if else statement with function call?

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is a more concise code on the below snippet.

```
def fun(x):
    return x + 2
a = 3
x = fun(a)
m = x if x == 3 else 4

print(m)
```

Would this work?

```
def fun(x):
    return x + 2

m = (x = fun(3)) if x == 3 else 4

print(m)
```

Comment: If you could use `fun(3)` in the theoretical one-liner, you could use `fun(3)` in `x = fun(3)`. Then, since you know `3 == 3`, `m = 3 if fun(3) == 3 else 4`. If this doesn’t work for your actual situation, please pick something representative of your actual situation.

Comment: Assignment is a statement, not an expression in Python. The code seems concise enough.

Comment: " Would this work? " ~ Why don't you try out yourself? (It won't. juanpa.arrivillaga said it right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're determined to make it a one-liner, and for some reason you can only call `fun` once, you can use a lambda function:

```
m = (lambda x: x if x == 3 else 4)(fun(a))
```

You can see that this isn't terribly readable, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Your trial code wouldn't work because you can't do assignment in an expression.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but it's not very readable/maintainable code:

```
m, = [ x if x == 3 else 4   for x in [fun(a)] ]
```

The assignment to `x` persists after it is used as the loop variable inside the list comprehension. Therefore, this one-liner has the effect of assigning both `m` and `x` in the way that you want.

Comment: And if you enjoy abusing `for` loops in ugly ways, I recommend the intellectual exercise of trying to get anything serious done in a Windows batch file.